# reinterpret_cast on unaligned memory

Tags: c++

Assuming the following code:

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    int b;
};

char* buffer = receivedFromSomeWhere();

A a = *reinterpret_cast<A*>(buffer + 1);
```

If `buffer + 0` is aligned on the size of an `int`, `buffer + 1` will be most likely on an unaligned memory. The default copy constructor will probably happily copy the two unaligned int members `a` and `b`.
On a x86/x64 architecture, except from slowing down the code, will it impact the copy construction of `a` in any nasty way?

I know that a good serialization would solve the unaligned memory problem (by maybe adding a padding somewhere in order that the `A` struct will be aligned in the `buffer`), but in my case i am not responsible for this part.

Comment: The fact it's unaligned probably won't matter on that architecture. However it's undefined behavior to access memory using a pointer to a different type than the data was stored with (with a few exceptions) (See string aliasing) so although it may well work on  your platform/compiler it's undefined behavior so unportable at best

Comment: I don't think it even slows it down on x86 unless you cross a cache line boundary.

Comment: @GManNickG Yeah that was my idea. But I wondered about reinterpret_cast, hence my question.

Comment: Note that things like `-fsanitize=undefined` will warn against such unaligned `reinterpret_cast`s, even on `x86_64`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The combination of C++ and using an x86_64 architecture is insufficient to guarantee that unaligned accesses are supported. You must have an additional guarantee from your specific C++ implementation that using the `reinterpret_cast` this way is supported, even if the address is unaligned. If you state your specific compiler and target system, somebody may be able to tell you whether it supports these operations.

In the absence of such a guarantee, you can use `memcpy` to copy bytes from an unaligned buffer into a POD (plain old data) object. A good compiler may optimize such accesses.

Comment: I already thought about memcpy but what I wanted to know the reinterpret_cast behaviour. Well, your response confirms that it is definitely an undefined behaviour even on some architecture trusted for its unaligned memory management. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have any example to a C++ compiler that generates code to identify unaligned memory access to a struct of two integers and handles this by a substitutional operation? Never seen this before with GCC, BCC or MSVC. So I am curious now.

Comment: +1 for mentioning `memcpy` over `reinterpret_cast`. Alignment issues aside, `reinterpret_cast` violates strict aliasing rule (unless you turn on a compiler flag). It's also worth noting that casting a raw buffer into an object is undefined behaviour in C++ (ok in C).

Answer (score -1):

The x86/x64 architecture allows unaligned access. As you already wrote this might have a performance impact. But since the CPU allows all operation there will be no other nasty problems.

You should keep in mind that the cache in modern processors reduces the memory cycles. So you won't have that much SDRAM cycles caused by the unaligned access.

The copy constructor is not related to the problem at all.

Comment: Alignment as seen in a C program is a function of the C implementation, not the underlying architecture. Typically a C implementation includes the compiler, the operating system, and the hardware, and possibly other components. The fact that the hardware supports unaligned access does not mean that the operating system or the C implementation allow it.

Comment: @EricPostpischil The reinterpret_cast exactly tells the compiler, that the developer knows it better. The compiler will accept the result of the cast. That's no question of a C implementation.

Comment: The result of the cast is not the question. Once the address is converted to a pointer to `A`, the compiler might use a normal load instruction to load it, and the operating system might have set the processor state to report exceptions for unaligned loads (when the state is set differently), even if the hardware supports unaligned loads. Then the program will fail. There are also other ways in which this can fail, even if the underlying hardware supports unaligned accesses.

Comment: Correction: I should have written C++ rather than C above. The point remains; it is the entire C++ implementation that ultimately determines its own properties, not just the hardware.

Comment: @EricPostpischil When you cast a pointer how is the operating system involved? What kind of (non-CPU) exception is passed from the OS to the calling process to report what? What state is set differently? Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: On IA-32 (“x86”) processors, the AC bit in the EFLAGS register and the AM flag in the CR) register control whether alignment checking is performed. These bits are set by the operating system. When alignment checking is enabled, various instructions will generate an exception for unaligned addresses, even though the underlying hardware is capable of supporting unaligned memory accesses. Thus, even though the compiler may not care for itself whether addresses are aligned or not, and the hardware could support them, the operating system can disallow them.